# Laravel 5.7 jobs queue not running async

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I'm trying to use Laravel 5.7 **jobs queue** to make some insertions/updates in my database and i problably made something wrong because when the job is called its seems to be blocking my application, therefore, not running asynchronously.
My code is in the following structure:

**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

**queue.php**

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
```

**job_caller.php**

```
method_name(){ 
  InsereProspeccao::dispatch($path, $evento, $equipe)->onQueue('jobs');
  retur some_msg_to_user;
}
```

**job_name.php**

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class InsereProspeccao implements ShouldQueue{

use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

  private $path = '';
  private $evento = '';
  private $equipe = '';


 public function __construct($path, $evento, $equipe){
     $this->path = $path;
     $this->evento = $evento;
     $this->equipe = $equipe;        
 }

   public function handle(){
      //all program logic
      //access DB for insert/update
   }

}
```

Obs.: I'M READING THE DOCUMENTATION, BUT I CANT FIND WHAT'S GOING WRONG !

Comment: You're using `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` so your queue connection will be synchronous

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` which basically has synchronous behavior.

Please follow below steps :

- Run `php artisan queue:table` which will create a migration for `jobs` table autimatically
- Run `php artisan migrate` which will create the table by running migration
- Change `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` and as per default, it will automatically take `jobs` table to manage the queues.
- Run `php artisan config:clear` to clear application configuration cache

That should be good to go. Check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#driver-prerequisites) for more help.

Comment: The one important additional step is [running the queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker) which is where most people seem to get a bit overwhelmed by.

Comment: well, @apokryfos. this one is new to me. So, when i deploy my project to a server i have to access it and install supervisor ?

Comment: There is no requirement as such to use supervisor, it would work without it as well. Its just to restart the queues if anything fails, but definitely good to have

Comment: @Wally the queue worker is a background process so as a minimum you need to be able to run background processes on your server. Supervisor is optional but nice to use since it makes things easier.

Comment: @apokryfos, now how do i run this when i deploy my app ? Do i have to acess the server via SSL and let the worker listening ?

Comment: @Wally yes you would need to do that. If your server is linux based you can use something like [`screen`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) to start the queue listener and then dettach the screen to allow it to run in the background.

Comment: You can also suffix the command with `&` so it runs in backgrund. like `php artisan queue:work &`

Comment: I had running it with `artisan serve` , I had to restart it to make it takes the change on file .env

Comment: Got two answers for the price of one question.  Thanks @apokryfos.  I had forgotten to start the queue worker.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` and it should be good to go.

You can also set up rabbitmq or other drivers, because their implementation is much more advanced and will be more production - ready. But database is a good start.