# 504 gateway timeout when using sync rather than database

Tags: laravel, queue

My problem is about using Supervisor as my worker what happens is when I upload my csv (users data) it will make a job that will shoot email until all the users in the csv are imported to the database. if I'm using `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` and run the `php artisan queue:work` manually I don't have problems running or uploading the csv but when I change the `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` to run with the Supervisor I got this weird 504 Gateway Error on uploading the CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: i removed the sqs settings in my supervisor configuration `php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --delay=20`

Answer (score 0):

is the file too large for your page to handle? If so, try editing the line on php.ini for file uploading.

Comment: well like i said if im running my queue connection as database i dont have problem uploading. i dont know if it is affecting the server when im uploading and the queue connection is set to sync rather than database

Comment: can this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834813/laravel-5-7-jobs-queue-not-running-async

Comment: i prefer using `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` rather than `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` so i can use the Supervisor but thanks for the link